# Check presence of loaded Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

How can you check for the presence of both Bundler as well as a Gemfile?

My initial guess was `defined?(Bundler) && File.exist?('Gemfile')`, but since you can have a Gemfile with a different name, this won’t cover all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

`Bundler::SharedHelpers.in_bundle?`

Answer (score 2):

When bundler has loaded, you can retrieve the Gemfile path from the global `ENV`, using the `'BUNDLE_GEMFILE'` key.